# No se como hacer una consulta en django

Tags: django

tengo un problema en el proyecto de clase y llevo aqui casi toda la tarde, no se mucho de django y a ver si me podeis ayuda, mi problema es que no se como se hace, necesito saber los grupos que no estan en la prueba que paso por parametros en Grupos_pruebas(esto es una m:n)

```
def controlpruebasid(request, nprueba):    
    try:
        p = Prueba.objects.get(id=nprueba)
        grupos = Grupos.objects.all()
        if p.id:             
            grupos_estan_en_la_prueba = Grupos_pruebas.objects.filter(prueba=p)
            #no se como se hace, necesito saber los grupos que no estan en la prueba que paso por parametros en Grupos_pruebas
            grupos_no_estan_en_la_prueba = Grupos.objects.exlucde(id=grupos_estan_en_la_prueba)

            contexto = {'nombreprueba':p.nombre, 'listasgrupossi':grupos_estan_en_la_prueba, 'listasgruposno':grupos_no_estan_en_la_prueba}
            return render(request,'yincana/controlpruebasid.html', contexto)
    except Prueba.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect('yincana:gestorpruebas')
```

[Aquí dejo el código](https://pastebin.com/uksEHdZk)

Comment: Adjunta el código de tus modelos en tu pregunta para poder solucionar tu problema con mayor facilidad.

Comment: El metodo correcto para el QuerySet es (exclude())[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters]. Estas obteniendo algún error?

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que grupos_estan_en_la_prueba puede tener uno o mas registros, lo que debes de hacer es decirle que excluya los que estan en grupos_estan_en_la_prueba.

```
grupos_no_estan_en_la_prueba = Grupos.objects.exclude(id__in=grupos_estan_en_la_prueba)
```

Answer (score 1):

La diferencia entre el conjunto de grupos que tienen asociado al menos una prueba y el conjunto de grupos que tienen la prueba especificada, da como resultado el conjunto de grupos que no tienen esa prueba en lo absoluto.

```
grupos_no_estan_en_la_prueba = Grupos_pruebas.objects.values('grupos').difference(grupos_estan_en_la_prueba.values('grupos'))
```

Teniendo en cuenta otras posibles soluciones planteadas, otra forma sería:

```
grupos_no_estan_en_la_prueba = Grupos.objects.exclude(id__in=grupos_estan_en_la_prueba.values('grupos'))
```

Comment: Da una breve explicación del código.

Comment: Apreciamos tu voluntad de contribuir, pero sólo un fragmento de código no es una respuesta de calidad. Por favor lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) y edita tu respuesta. También, aprovecha y [haz el recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla.